# Remix.run + Cloudflare worker environmental variables

Tags: cloudflare, cloudflare-workers, remix.run

I'm trying run Remix.run with Cloudflare workers. How might I access environmental variables related to Cloudflare data persistence services (such as D1) in Remix.run data loader functions?

I have "bound" the worker via `wrangler.toml` and can access the service via wrangler.

```ini
[[ d1_databases ]]
binding = "DB" # i.e. available in your Worker on env.DB
database_name = "Example"
database_id = "123-456-789"
```

I'm able to access other environmental variables from the global scope using `.env.vars` but can't seem to access `DB`.

Answer (score 1):

In Cloudflare Workers, environment variables are exposed on the `global` object. I recommend making them all caps.

```js
declare var DATABASE_ID: string
console.log(DATABASE_ID)
```

Comment: I'm able to access environmental variables stored in `.dev.vars` in the way you mention but for whatever reason can't seem to access the `DB` or `env` variable.

Comment: This is only true for Workers using the service worker syntax. There's a new syntax Cloudflare is calling "module workers". ["When deploying a Module Worker, any bindings will not be available as global runtime variables."](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/platform/environment-variables/#environmental-variables-with-module-workers)

Answer (score 0):

The DB binding works for me using the new [module syntax](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/learning/migrating-to-module-workers/). Note that this is distinct from [the old service worker syntax](https://blog.cloudflare.com/workers-javascript-modules/). Durable objects [require module Workers](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/learning/migrating-to-module-workers/#advantages-of-migrating) - perhaps this is also true for the new D1?